# Yii2 query search with gridview

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i would like to do a query search something like:
select * from task t, activity a, project p where t.activityid = a.activityid and a.projectid = p.projectid and p.userid =25

I do understand my task, is related with activity, so how can i know the project created, task is related to the project.

in my task view-

```
$query1s = new Query;
$query1s->select('*')
    ->from('task','activity','project') 
    ->where(['task.activityid' => 'activity.activityid']) 
    ->andWhere(['activity.projectid' => 'project.projectid']) 
    ->andWhere(['project.userid' => $userID]);

$command = $query1s->createCommand();
$datas = $command->queryAll();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query1s,
]);
```

Comment: show your code what you did.

Comment: in my task view-
 $query1s = new Query;
 $query1s->select('*')
                ->from('task','activity','project')
                ->where(['task.activityid'=>'activity.activityid'])
                ->andWhere(['activity.projectid'=>'project.projectid'])
                ->andWhere(['project.userid'=>$userID]);
$command = $query1s->createCommand();$datas = $command->queryAll();
                   
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                    'query' => $query1s,
                ]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you should create a `search model` from the main model and extend the search model class from the main model class.

After that you should create a public method called `search` with parameter. Then you do the filterings and querying data in your method without executing the query. When the query is completely created, just pass it to the `dataprovider` whitout executing it and you can do whatever you need to do with that data and handle other things in your controller and view.

Here is two URLs to complete tutorials to help you out:

[Filter & Sort by calculated/related fields in GridView Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/)

[Displaying, Sorting and Filtering Model Relations on a GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/)

Comment: I have solve the issue, which I had forgotten I could use my activity table to join  the 2 other table to get result, and thanks to you I have able to output the result as well